# Same Progress Dialog through Activities and Fragments.

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, fragment, progressdialog

Scenario Activities :
1. In Activity1 , on a button click I start an Async Task, shows a progress dialog.
2. On post execute of Activity1's Async Task, I dismiss the Progress dialog and Switch to Activity2.
3. On Activity2's OnResume() I call an AsyncTask,shows a progress dialog.
4. On Activity2's AsyncTask onPostExecute I dismiss the Progress Dialog and then inflate the layout.
5. Issue: Activity1 and Activity2 start and dismiss progress bar one after the other. Which is not     visually appealing.
6. What I want to do ? : I want to carry the progress dialog from Activity1 , not dismiss it until 
Activity2' Asynctask's onPostExecute.  Change the progress dialogs's title when the activity      switches.
7. Solution? Work around? Jugaad ?